# jQuery write element just after the Ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, append

Hello I have a jQuery function that will send to a php file some info. The PHP file will do the stuff it has supposed to do and will generate some HTML code. I am fine until here.

The problem is that I have then to take the HTML results generated by this PHP file and write them in the page where the Ajax call has been created, simply by appending it after a DIV or inside a DIV or whatever.

This is the jQuery function I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var idGenre = $("#txtGenre option:selected").val();
var html = $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "GetSubGenreData.php",
             data: "id=" + idGenre,
             async: false
             }).responseText;

});
```

The DIV that must be updated with the HTML results taken from the PHP file GetSubGenreData.php is:

```
<div id ="divSubGenre"></div>
```

Now lets say the PHP file will return a select box, something like this:

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
etc...
</select>
```

This select box must be appended just after the DIV `<div id ="divSubGenre"></div>` or by simply replacing this DIV with the returned Select Box. Nothing impossible for a good jQuery developer. But I am not.

I just need the function to write the HTML results from the PHP file in the right DIV.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your success callback

```
success:function(html){

$("#divSubGenre").append(html);
}
```

if you want to replace the container div with the ajax response

```
success:function(html){

$("#divSubGenre").replaceWith(html);
}
```

if the `div` to which you are appending the results is not empty then to insert after the div use `after`

```
success:function(html){
$("#divSubGenre").after(html);
}
```

so your final code may look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var idGenre = $("#txtGenre option:selected").val();
var html = $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "GetSubGenreData.php",
             data: {id:idGenre},
             async: false,
             success:function(html){
               $("#divSubGenre").append(html);
             }
            });

});
```

[`jquery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[`jquery replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

[`jquery append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[`jquery after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

**update**

```
$("#txtGenre").change(function(){
//get the update value here
var idGenre = $("#txtGenre option:selected").val();
  $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "GetSubGenreData.php",
             data: {id:idGenre},
             async: false,
             success:function(html){
               $("#divSubGenre").html(html);
             }
            });

});
```

[`jquery change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

**yet another update**
about the comment to show the result on page load, if i have understood the scenario well you can have two divs on the page like

```
<div id="divSubGenre"></div>
<div id="divonLoad"></div>
```

on the page load do the ajax call and append the result to `#divonLoad` and in the `success` callback of your ajax call that is inside the `change` event handler do this

```
success:function(html){
$("#divonLoad").fadeOut("slow").remove(); removes the div that was holding the result on page load
$("#divSubGenre").html(html);
}
```

Comment: Also this one works. But I have the same question. When idGenre changes the HTML result does not get updated. Why? I need a way to update the result EVERYTIME the idGenre Value changes. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: from where the idGenere is changing? is it a dropdown? or an input field?

Comment: I will for sure!! Last question. It is now adding the HTML result ONLY when the idGenre changes. Is there a way to show the first result always. I mean when the page loads there is no select box there, until idGenre changes. I would need to show that anyway, because the first value of idGenre will be available anyway. It is already there, so I need to show the result, even if there is no Change. Can you help me?

Comment: @DiegoP. you mean that the first result is visible always or until the value is changed?

Comment: Yes. We already have as soon as the page load a value for idGenre. So I would like to show the first results, even if there is no onChange. Right now it does not show the result until idGenre get changed. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Add an HTML `dataType` and a `success` method to your AJAX call:

```
// No need to return the responseText as a variable
updateSelectHtml = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetSubGenreData.php",
    data: "id=" + idGenre,
    async: false,
    // Make sure the return is formatted as html
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      // The return HTML data is appended after the div.
      $("#divSubGenre").html(data);
    }
 });
};

// Bind the function to #txtGenre onchange
$("#txtGenre").change(updateSelectHtml);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it should happen everytime the value idGenre change. Instead it happens now only on the first page load. But if I change the value of idGenre it remains the same. How do I do that will change everytime the idGenre value changes?

Comment: @DiegoP. See changes above - the whole ajax call is now wrapped in a function, and that function is bound to the onchange method of `#txtGenre`

Comment: This function writes and writes the returned HTML results. IT is not updating the previous result. It appends unlimited results one just after the previous one. How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to replace the div contents you can use `.html(data to be replace)`

Comment: @DiegoP. Sorry - changed the `.after()` method to `.html()` to replace contents.